# Copying fields from one layer to another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers

I am new to QGIS. I need to create hundreds of shapefile layers with the same fields but different points and attribute values:

1. The first shapefile one I created with 12 fields (columns).
2. To create the second, I duplicated the first one.
3. Unchecked the first one to guarantee its safe.
4. In the attribute table, deleted all the points of the second since
   the only thing important here is to keep the fields titles.
5. Start to map new points with its new attributes.

After click on save layer edits, all my points on the first layer are gone. I can not understand why the points and data on the first layer are being deleted.

Comment: Duplicating the layer in QGIS Canvas does not mean creating a new shapefile in your hard disk, you are still referencing to the same shapefile in your HDD. To create a new shapefile you need to right-click -> export as new shapefile.

Comment: @ahmadhanb please make this an answer so it can be accepted and upvoted

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you very much. The comment was added as an answer.

Comment: There should really be a warning about this behavior in QGIS. The other day, one of my colleagues was casually telling me about what they was working on and they had duplicated some layer and had started deleting things in the duplicate and ... wait, wait, wait, say that again!? In the end, I happened to have a local backup, but it could have been really bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Duplicating the layer in QGIS Canvas does not mean creating a new shapefile in your hard disk (HDD), you are still referencing to the same shapefile in your HDD. To create a new shapefile you need to `right-click -> Export -> Save feature as` and create a new shapefile.

Before exporting to a new shapefile, you can uncheck the fields that you do not need and check the fields the you want to keep in the new shapefile

[image]